# Menu with category 2 category combined

Tags: categories, menus

I need to create 2 category menu in my wordpress site. One in the sidebar, one in the content. In the content I need to have only ingredient menu, so

- fish
- chicken

...and so on.

In the sidebar I need to have

- first dishes

  ```
   - fish 

   - chicken
  ```
- second dishes

  ```
     - fish

     - chicken
  ```

  Which is the best way to achieve this?

Better if automatic add when I add categories.

If I use the subcategories I'll have 2 fish and 2 chicken categories and I don't think is the best way. If I use 2 categories I have in the first dishes and second dishes all ingredient without distinction. You have some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain the logics of 2 menus displayed on same page. 
I believe you menu structure is as follows:

```
first dishes
 - fish 
 - chicken
second dishes
 - fish
 - chicken
```

So your main categories are ones like "first dishes" and "second dishes"
How do you want to show main categories - as separate menus?

And same question to sub menus like "fish", "chicken"
There will be several menus like:

1) Related to "second dishes"
     - fish 
     - chicken

2) Related to "second dishes"
     - fish
     - chicken

Or theme menus will be displayed on some recipe posts, and each post will have category relation